# How to remove unwanted values and display null instead

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following piece of code which extracts the data from a MySQL table. I would like to display null in the table cell for certain values like Tnex>=40, Mode>=20 etc. When I tried to do it in SQL query with where clause,  the rows that don't fit the criteria are not displayed on the table. Instead, I need the rows to be displayed, but just the values to be shown null or empty.

For example, in a certain row if "Tnex" >= 40, then the table cell should be null.  How can I do this? I want to show null instead of certain numbers (e.g, if my criteria is for "Tnex" is like Tnex<=10, then I would like to show "null" for  the values from 1 to 10, and only display the rest of the values. how can I do this?

```
<table class="tbnar">
 <tr>
<th>Date</th> 
<th>Snex</th>
<th>Tnex</th>
<th>Mode</th>
</tr>


 <?php

  include ("config.php");

  $sql = "SELECT Date, Snex, Tnex, Mode FROM datatb";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 

   {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Snex"]. "</td><td>". $row["Tnex"]. "</td><td>".  $row["Mode"]. "</td></tr>";


  }

</table>
```

Comment: Do you want every column of the row to display `null`. Or just that one column?

Comment: For example, if I define <=10 for a column, then only the numbers above 10 should be displayed in that column.  Basically, I don't want to display all numbers, only numbers in a specific range.

Comment: There can be more than one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT Date, 
       Snex, 
       CASE WHEN Tnex < 40 THEN Tnex END AS Tnex, 
       CASE WHEN Mode < 20 THEN Mode END AS Mode
FROM   datatb
```

Comment: I'd like to use your solution, after AbraCadaver's comment. but I keep getting `Notice: Undefined index: Tnex` error in the sql query.

Comment: @user761065 edited my answer to add aliases so you can keep the same PHP code to handle the query's results.

Answer (score 2):

Check the condition and set a variable to either string `NULL`, empty space or the value, then use that.  In this case `$Tnex`:

```
$Tnex = ($row["Tnex"] >= 40) ? '&nbsp;' : $row["Tnex"];

echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Snex"] . "</td><td>" . $Tnex . "</td><td>" .  $row["Mode"] . "</td></tr>";
```